# MAXWAIT parameter for bridge on Debian Linux boot

Tags: linux, debian, kvm-virtualization

I can't seem to find MAXWAIT setting (bridge initialization time) anywhere in /etc on Debian 7.2 x64. Sometimes default 20s  is too short for some reason and I'd like to set it longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you configure your bridge. Did you use the `/etc/network/interfaces` to define them? If so you can use this parameter to change MAXWAIT:

```
bridge_maxwait 20
```

Apparently that's only available in the newer versions: [reference](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=549696)